# Из выпадающих список выбрать один из них, тогда перенаправить запись на одну из них

Tags: python, django

У меня есть три страницы. И на базу данных есть 3 выпадающие список. Если из выпадающих список выбрать один из них, тогда перенаправить запись на одну из них.

например, страницы

```
1-Касса
2-Менеджер физ лиц
3-Менеджер юр лицо
```

Выпадающие списки

```
1-Касса
2-Менеджер физ лиц
3-Менеджер юр лицо
```

Если из выпадающих списков выбираю Кассу, тогда должна появляться запись на странице Касса. Если физ лицо, тогда на странице физ лицо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**models.py**

```
  from django.db import models
  class News(models.Model):
    MANAGERS = [
        ('Касса', 'Касса'),
        ('Менеджер физическое лицо', 'Менеджер физическое лицо'),
        ('Менеджер юридический лицо', 'Менеджер юридический лицо'),

    ]
    fio = models.CharField(('ФИО'), max_length=50)
    komu = models.CharField(('Кому?'), max_length=50, choices=MANAGERS)
    text = models.TextField(('Суть обращение?'))
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import News


def home(request):
    data = {
        'news': News.objects.all(),
        'title': 'Очередь БАНК ЦЕНТР КРЕДИТ'
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', data)


def qassa(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/qassa.html', {'title': 'Касса'})

def fizface(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/fizface.html', {'title': 'Физ лицо'})

def urface(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/urface.html', {'title': 'Юр лицо'})

def queue_create(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/queue_create.html', {'title': 'Создать очередь'})
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/main.html' %}


{% block main_section %}
    {% for post in news %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <div class="alert alert-warning mt-2">
        <h2>{{ post.fio }}</h2> <h5>{{  post.komu  }}</h5>{{post.text  }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock main_section %}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: вопрос можно нормально формулировать? когда вы добавляете запись, после сохранения отправлять на страницу, соответствующую полю "Кому"?